# Gnome not launching on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome-tweaks

```
 gnome-tweaks
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gnome-tweaks", line 13, in <module>
    import gi
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from . import _gi
ImportError: cannot import name '_gi' from partially initialized module 'gi' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py)
```